# Best practice to update bulk data in table used for reporting in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a table for reporting purpose where I am storing data for about 50 columns and at some time interval my scheduler executes a service which processes other tables and fill up data in my flat table.

Currently I am deleting and inserting data in that table But I want to know if this is the good practice or should I check every column in every row and update it if any change found and insert new record if data does not exists.

FYI, total number of rows which are being reinserted is 100k+.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question that can only really be answered with access to your environment and discussion on your personal requirements.  Obviously this is not possible via Stack Overflow.

This means you will need to make this decision yourself.

The information you need to understand to be able to do this are the types of table updates available and how you can achieve them, normally referred to as [Slowly Changing Dimensions](https://adatis.co.uk/introduction-to-slowly-changing-dimensions-scd-types/).  There are several different types, each with their own advantages, disadvantages and optimal use cases.

Once you understand the *how* of getting your data to incrementally update as required, you can then look at the *why* and whether the extra processing logic required to achieve this *is actually worth it*.  Your dataset of a few hundred thousand rows of data is not large and probably may therefore not need this level of processing just yet, though that assessment will depend on how complex and time consuming your current process is and how long you have to run it.

Comment: Totally agreed with your point. As per my current approach I am storing data in temp table after process and then I delete all records in my reporting table then insert it again from the temporary table to avoid checking all columns in all rows for update.

So, as per this I am just want to understand what takes more processing. Deleting and inserting one row with 50 column or checking all columns if any change is found then updating all 50 columns

Comment: @Abhi619 As I said in my answer, that depends *entirely* on your environment, which we don't have access to.  You are going to need to either do the learning yourself and apply it to your situation or hire someone in to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably faster to repopulate the table of 100k rows.  To do an update, you still need to:

- generate all the rows to insert
- compare values in every row
- update the values that have changed

The expense of updating rows is heavily on the logging and data movement operations *at the data page level*.  In addition, you need to bring the data together.

If the update is updating a significant portion of rows, perhaps even just a few percent of them, then it is likely that all data pages will be modified.  So the I/O is pretty similar.

When you simply replace the table, you will start by either dropping the table or truncating it.  Those are relatively cheap operations because they are not logged at the row level.  Then you are inserting into the table.  Inserting 100,000 rows from one table to another should be pretty fast.

The above is general guidance.  Of course, if you are only changing 3 rows in the table each day, then `update` is going to be faster.  Or, if you are adding a new layer of data each day, then just an `insert`, with a handful of changed historical values might be a fine approach.